# React Native - Style is not consistent across multiple devices

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have learned react native and started developing a basic payment app . I am using flex to arrange elements inside the screen. Flex layout is consistent across all devices, but if I apply style to some components inside flux , it is not consistent across devices.

For example I have added a drop down component (Expiry Month) inside a view which is inside flex and added margin top as 25 px . If I open the app in Iphone 8 plus, it is displaying as expected, but if I open it in Iphone 8 it is touching the component above it (Even I tried changing the unit to percentage instead of pixels but still the same behavior) . I am not sure why the style is not responsive across multiple devices , can someone please guide me on how to make the styling responsive.

Please take a look at the below screenshots and code snippet . Thank you !!!

**Iphone 8 Plus**

[image]

**Iphone 8**

[image]

**Code Snippet of the element**

```
    <View
  style={{
    flex: 0.1,
    flexDirection: "row",
  }}
>
  <RNPickerSelect
    items={CardExpiryMonth.getMonth()}
    style={{
      ...pickerSelectStyles1,

      placeholder: { color: "grey", fontSize: 15, fontFamily: myFont },
      iconContainer: {
        top: 35,
      },
    }}
    placeholder={{
      label: "Exp Month",
      color: "green",
    }}
    placeholderTextColor="red"
    useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
    textInputProps={{ underlineColor: "yellow" }}
    Icon={() => {
      return <Ionicons name="md-arrow-down" size={24} color="gray" />;
    }}
  />
</View>
```

```
const pickerSelectStyles1 = StyleSheet.create({
inputIOS: {
fontSize: 16,
height: 50,
paddingVertical: 12,
paddingHorizontal: 10,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: "gray",
borderRadius: 4,
color: "black",
paddingRight: 30, // to ensure the text is never behind the icon
width: 130,
top: 25,
left: 8 }
```

Comment: I think this is because flex:.1. That means if area have 100px height it will allocate 10px to the element. Same will be applied to different iPhone sizes

Comment: Hi SaachiTech,

Thanks for your comments, Even if flex is the problem, how to fix it ?
This is how all the tutorials in online mentioned to apply flex. Can you pls suggest some solution to make styles responsive to all devices.

Comment: What does the parent container look like? can you provide minimal reproducible on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lifecycle-demo-showcase?file=index.js) or [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-xgzdk)?

Comment: @onkarruikar this is my code: https://pastebin.com/EV5crvBQ, it works perfectly on pixel 5, but on other devices i get different css, some of the components outside my width screen and so on

Comment: why in the question do you say marginTop but in the code it just says top?  Top wont do much because you don't have position absolute.  change it to marginTop and it may work...

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do is give margin to your parent view. So the code would be.

```
<View
  style={{
    marginTop: 25, // For only iOS (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 25 : 0,
    flex: 0.1,
    flexDirection: "row",
  }}
>
  <RNPickerSelect
    // your code
  />
</View>
```

If you want to do changes in `RNPickerSelect`'s style SO as you can check given example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@lfkwtz/react-native-picker-select) you are using it wrong you are putting inputIOS into styles that become something like below code.

```
  <RNPickerSelect
    style={{ inputIOS: {...your style} }} // this is wrong
  />
```

inputIOS properties should be direct properties of style.

Also find one more thing that you used `top: 25,` for giving margin top `top` property use in case of absolute position. So, Please confirm RNPickerSelect using absolute position otherwise use `marginTop: 25,` instead.

Let me know If you have any more query.

Comment: thanks for ur answer.

Comment: My pleasure @chikabala Please accept answer so other can trust.

Comment: i would love to accept it, but it's not my question :(